# Orthogonal set summation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\{v_1,v_2,....,v_k\}$ be an orthogonal set in $V$, and let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k\}$ be scalars. Prove that
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i\right\|^2
= \sum_{i=1}^k |a_i^2| \, \|v_i\|^2.
$$
I understand the concept, but I'm not sure how to write it our correctly. 
Here's my attempt:
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i\right\|^2
=\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i,\ \sum_{j=1}^m a_jv_j\right\rangle
$$
Since the $v_i$'s are orthogonal, the inner product will be zero whenever $i \neq j$.

So, 
\begin{align*}
&=\langle a_1v_1,\,a_1v_1\rangle + \langle a_2v_2,\,a_2v_2\rangle + \ldots + \langle a_kv_k,\,a_kv_k\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2 \langle v_i,v_i\rangle\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i^2| \, \|v_i\|^2.
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is, though there're some little things that hopefully you understand well and don't have to prove, say $$\langle av,av\rangle=a\overline a\langle v,v\rangle=|a|^2||v||^2$$

Comment: This looks very good. Just as a note, you can change the index in the second summation in your inner product to $j$, but the upper bound should still be $k$; you currently have it as $m$, which doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, i'll add it in, just in case. Thanks!

Comment: @AWertheim You're right, ill fix it. Thank you!